# Chrome quick find (ctrl + f) re-positions elements in document

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Google Chrome version 29.0.1547.62 m.

I have some DIV elements hidden from the view via their parent's CSS attribute overflow set to hidden and those DIV elements are re-positioned using CSS attribute transform.

When I open find (ctrl + F), type in word that is found in DIV, the DIV is moved by browser.

How to prevent Chrome from re-positioning my DIV elements while using search function?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do. `overflow:hidden` doesn't prevent the overflowing content from scrolling into view, it just doesn't show scrollbars for it. Selecting the element that is partially or entirely out of the parent's bounds will scroll the content until the element is  entirely or as much as possible in view. As you've probably guessed, that is the feature of chrome's search that gives you problems.

Answer (score 0):

Element with `overflow:hidden;`, triggers the *onscroll* event. You can listen on it and scroll again manually.

Tested on Chrome 41 / OSX.